# django-compressor caches SASS compiled files and doesn't update them after changes

Tags: python, django, caching, django-compressor

My django-compressor properly compiles SASS files containing `@import`, but then caches them and doesn't update when imported files have been changed. I don't get it, I thought that if SASS compiler isn't added to COMPRESS_CACHEABLE_PRECOMPILERS, they shouldn't be cached at all.

My setup:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/coffeescript', 'coffee --compile --stdio'),
    ('text/sass', 'django_libsass.SassCompiler'),
)
COMPRESS_CACHE_BACKEND = 'compressor'
COMPRESS_CACHEABLE_PRECOMPILERS = (
    'text/coffeescript',
)
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
```

It worked fine previously with `COMPRESS_ENABLED` not set to `True` (as in, files were compiled but not compressed and cached).

Comment: I opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/772

Comment: I didn't find any answer. We had to manually remove these files every build.